# Add commits of downloaded repo to the original commit history and allow pull request

Tags: git

I'm new to git and started my project without fully understand how git works and eventually got myself into this dilemma if someone can point me the right way to solve this I will be very appreciated.

I've got an existed Github repo (a.k.a ClientMaster) with 100+ commit on the master branch, I "downloaded" the repo, unzip and started my work (which makes me lose the commit history, dumb move) and made changes, resulting in 10 commits, all on a master branch.

Now I want to push my downloaded repo back to ClientMaster as a new branch and send a pull request, I can push it with -f but it shows "nothing to compare because two branches have a completely different history" if I try to send a PR. My problem is, by all means, am I allowed to merge my local repo with the original repo meanwhile keeping all my newly made commits.

In a graphic way:

```
ClientMaster: -0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0
Downloaded local Repo:                -1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
                                      |
                                      Downloaded to local(no previous 100+ commit history)
```

If I got it right, I must have a repo with the commit history of ...-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
so I'm allowed to push back to ClientMaster and send a pull request, right?

I've tried merging, rebase, cherry-pick, `--allow-unrelated-histories`, but none of them seems to work.

Please point me the right way.

Comment: How about just cloning it and overwriting the folder with your changes? The git-relevant stuff should work this way!

Comment: When you download as zip, you don't get the history with the zip, without the history, git cannot merge if automatically. Do you still remember what the last commit on GitHub was when you downloaded the project? Without this it is impossible to fix the situation.

Comment: That's a quick reply, thanks guys!!  I'm totally new to git, please point me out if i have the wrong concept. 

First, if i clone clientmaster and overwrite the folder, not only do i lost previous 100+ commit history ( i checked it with "git log" after cloned to local, and it says repo doesn't have commits yet), but all changes will be wrapped into a commit, right? BUT I'm hoping to preserve all of the ten commits.

And yes, now i get that without history git can't merge automatically and i would be more than happy if i could merge it manually, but i just can't figure it out.

Comment: @Ferrybig do you mean that if somehow i get to replicate a same commit as the last commit on github and make it as the first commit of my local repo, git can automatically recognize my new-pushed branch has differed from the remote master since that particular commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ferrybig commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264157/add-commits-of-downloaded-repo-to-the-original-commit-history-and-allow-pull-req#comment102896282_58264157), when you used the "download a zip file" option and then created your own repository with `git init`, you didn't get *their* **repository** at all.  You just got *one snapshot*.

What you need to do at this point is to combine two repositories into one.  This is always at least a little bit messy.  If you're lucky, it will only be a *very* little bit messy, but it is still a bit painful.  If you had more commits—say, 500 of your own instead of 10—you'd want to automate this or use another approach, but with only 10 or so of your own commits, you might be able to do this with a relatively simple, conceptually-speaking anyway, approach.

What we're going to do here is get all the commits from *both* repositories into a *third* repository, and then do some surgery.  Exactly what surgery to do is up to you, but I'll go with using `git cherry-pick`, perhaps with one first hand-rolled commit if needed (we'll see why in a bit).  You'll need some background to understand what's going on, though.

#### What's in a repository

First, let's take a quick look at what a repository is.  To a first approximation, a Git repository is a database holding a bunch of commits.  That is, Git is all about *commits*.  Commits hold files, so a repository holds files indirectly, but the key items are the commits.  Each commit holds a snapshot—the set of files, as of the state they had when you (or whoever) made the commit—along with some metadata: the name and email address of the author of the commit, and so on.

Repositories do also have branch names.  They're useful—especially to humans—and they form a sort of secondary database in the repository, but they're not nearly as important as the commits.  Mostly, what they do is let you (and Git) *find* commits.  The problem with commits is that their true names are big ugly hash IDs, which no human can really deal with.

When you clone a repository, you get all of its commits.  These go into a *new* repository (initially empty, then filled with their commits).  You also get its branch names, but your Git immediately *renames* all of their branch names: if they have `master`, you get `origin/master`.  If they have `develop`, you get `origin/develop`.  Then, as the last step of a `git clone`, your Git runs `git checkout _____` with the blank filled in with some name: typically `master`, but this depends on your `git clone` command and/or instructions from their repository.  This last `git checkout` step *creates* your local `master` (or whatever other name) based on the `origin/master` (or origin/whatever) your Git just made from *their* `master` (or whatever).

You didn't do this initially, so you didn't get their commits.  That means the first commit that you made in *your* repository is entirely unrelated to all of their commits.  That's what makes joining your repository, and your commits, with a new clone you can make of their repository so messy: they just won't join up easily.

Note that nothing about any *existing* commit can *ever* be changed.  We can, however, make new commits, sometimes by *copying* a commit, or its effect.  We'll make use of this to copy either 9, or all 10, of your 10 commits.

#### How commits relate to each other

We already mentioned that the "true name" of a commit is its hash ID.  The hash ID of any commit is unique to that one commit: no other commit will *ever* have that hash ID.  But every Git in the universe will agree that *that* commit—that one, and no other—gets *that* hash ID.  The way Git does this is that the hash ID is a cryptographic hash of the contents of the commit, including the name of the person who made it and a time stamp of exactly *when* they made it.  You can make a commit with the same contents again, but if your name is not their name, and/or you make it at a different time, you've made a new and different commit.  The only way to get the same commit ID is to make the same commit at the same time using the same name, *and*—crucially—having the same *history*, or parent hash ID(s), as their commit.

Now, having made some initial commit—which gets some seemingly random hash ID—if you make a *second* commit, that second commit's hash ID depends not only on the contents, and your name, and the current time, but also on the *first* commit's hash ID.  Your third commit depends in part on your second commit's hash ID too.

So: each commit stores the raw hash ID of its immediate parent commit or commits.  That not only affects the hash ID of that particular commit, it also allows Git to string commits together, albeit backwards.  If their repository has 1000 commits, one of them is first, and one of the last few commits is what you used to make your first commit.

Assuming all of their commits are in a nice simple linear chain (this never happens in real life but it's good for examples, and almost certainly sufficient here, and presumably *your* ten commits are still all nice and linear—if they're not we have a bigger problem), we could draw them like this, using letters to stand in for the actual commits:

```
A <-B ... <-G <-H
```

(well, OK, this is just 8 commits—you can see why Git uses big ugly hash IDs, rather than single uppercase letters as we'll run out after 26 of them!).  This representation shows the internal parent linkage as arrows.  It's easier to draw it as lines, as long as we remember (whenever needed) that the arrows all go backwards, rather than forwards.

Their name `master` will identify their *last* commit:

```
A--B--...--G--H   <-- master
```

The name `master` identifies, or *points to*, their last commit `H`; that commit identifies—points to—its parent `G`, which points to its own parent, and so on.  The chain stops pointing backwards only when it reaches their very first commit `A`.

Meanwhile, in *your* repository, your ten commits look similar, but to draw them, I'll start with the letter `N`:

```
N--O--...--V--W   <-- master
```

Note that `N` is the *first* commit in your repository.  It has no parent.

#### How we'll glue these together

What we'll do is make a third repository, starting it out empty:

```
mkdir third; cd third; git init
```

Now we'll add the ability to access both other repositories through two new *remotes*.  A remote is just a short name for a URL—where there's some other Git—that also provides the ability to remember that other Git's branches.  So we will do:

```
git remote add one ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

(or use `https` or whatever you would use to clone it), and then:

```
git remote add two /path/to/tencommitrepo
```

We now have remotes named `one` and `two`.  We'll use them with `git fetch` to get *all* of both sets of commits:

```
git fetch one
git fetch two
```

Now, in this third repository, we have no `master`, but we do have `one/master` and `two/master`—these are *remote-tracking names* that remember `one`'s `master` and `two`'s master respectively—and we can draw them like this:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- one/master

N--O--...--W   <-- two/master
```

Remember that we cannot change *any* of these existing commits.  But we can make *new* commits!  Let's start by making a local `master` branch.  Ideally, we should make this point whichever commit is find-able from the name `one/master` that is exactly, totally, 100% identical to the snapshot in commit `N`.

#### Starting the rebuild, if you can't find a 100% match

If we can't find one, it's likely good enough to use commit `H`.  If we *can* find one, we can let it subsume commit `N`—the 100%-matching snapshot in, say, `G` is just as good as the snapshot in `N`, or actually *better* because it has the right history behind it.  But if we can't find it, we'll do this:

```
git branch master one/master
git checkout master
```

That will fill this new third repository's index (from which new commits get made) and work-tree from their commit `H`.  Now, since `H` and `N` aren't really identical, we'll make a new branch we'll call `rebuild` for now, *also* pointing to commit `H`:

```
git checkout -b rebuild
```

which gives us this:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- one/master, master, rebuild

N--O--...--W   <-- two/master
```

Now we'll get the *contents* of commit `N` into our index and work-tree so that we're ready to make a new commit.  To do this, we'll use a so-called *plumbing* command, `git read-tree`.  We need to find the hash ID of commit `N`, or (if your count is exact and it really is ten commits) use the name `two/master~9`:

```
 N--O--P--Q--R--S--T--U--V--W
~9 ~8 ~7 ~6 ~5 ~4 ~3 ~2 ~1
```

Each number here steps back that many parent links, so `~9` counts back 9 times, from `W` to `N`.  It's probably easier (though it requires some care) to run `git log --oneline two/master` in a command-line window and cut-and-paste the raw hash IDs, though:

```
git read-tree -u <hash>
```

A `git status` will now show some changes that are ready to commit, because it will compare commit `H` to what we've put into the index (and work-tree) from commit `N`.  So now we'll commit this, even if it rolls back some important change—you'll just have to fix that up later:

```
git commit -C <hash-of-N>
```

The `-C` option copies the commit message from commit `N`.  We've just made a whole new commit on our current branch `rebuild` so now our third repository has:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- one/master, master
            \
             I   <-- rebuild

N--O--...--W   <-- two/master
```

Commit `I`'s snapshot exactly matches that of commit `N`.  Its commit *message* is that of commit `N` as well.  (Use `git commit -c <hash>`, lowercase c, instead of `-C` if you want a chance to edit the message.)

If you *do* find an exact-match commit, we don't need this step at all: we'll start a bit differently.

#### Starting the rebuild from a 100% match

If we have a 100% match of the snapshot in `N` vs that in, say, commit `G`, what we'll want to do is create our `master` as before, but create our `rebuild` pointing to commit `G` instead:

```
git branch master one/master
git checkout <hash-of-G>
git checkout -b rebuild
```

Now, since the snapshot in `G` matches that in `N`, we *won't* bother to copy `N` at all, and now the rebuild method joins up with what we did when we had to copy `N` to `I` to come after `H`.

#### We can now copy the rest of the commits with `git cherry-pick`

Now that `rebuild` points to a commit that exactly matches commit `N`—whether that's, say, `G`, or a new `I`—we'll run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-O>
```

(or again if the counting is exact, `git cherry-pick two/master~8`).

What Git will do here is compare commits `N` and `O`, to see what changes you made.  It will then do its best to apply those same changes to the current commit.

(Technically, Git actually does a full three-way merge here, using `N` as the merge base, `O` as the other commit, and `G` or `I`—whichever is the current commit—as the current commit.  This three-way merge can have conflicts, in the general case, but since `G` or `I` exactly matches `N`, it won't have any conflicts at all, and the cherry-pick will succeed easily.)

The result is either:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- one/master, master
            \
             I--J   <-- rebuild

N--O--...--W   <-- two/master
```

or:

```
A--B--...--G--H   <-- one/master, master
            \
             J   <-- rebuild

N--O--...--W   <-- two/master
```

Either way, new commit `J` is a *copy* of commit `O`, just as its parent—whether that's `G` or `I`—is a *copy* of commit `N`.

The difference between these copies and the originals is that the copies have the right *parent*.  The linkage from each commit to its parent *is* the history in a Git repository, so this new repository is building up the history you *want*.

We now simply repeat the cherry-pick with each remaining commit.  We can have cherry-pick itself do all the work by running:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-O>..two/master
```

to select every commit after `O` up to and including commit `W`.  (In fact, we could have done this with the first `git cherry-pick` command, but by doing it manually, we make sure we've got the right hashes in place and that everything is working, before we turn all of Git's automatic machinery loose at its top speed.  Also, if you have a truly ancient version of Git, it might not *support* a ranged `cherry-pick`; in that case, you'll really have to do each one by hand here.)

The final result of all this is—well, we have a bit of a problem *drawing* it here, because the one-letter names run out quickly, but:

```
A--B--...--H   <-- one/master, master
            \
             I--J--K--L--M--o--o--...--o   <-- rebuild

N--O--...--W   <-- two/master
```

where `I` is a copy of either `N` or `O`, `J` is a copy of the next commit from the chain that ends at `two/master`, and so on.

#### You're done, or almost done, at this point

At this point, if you "lost" something good from commit `H`, it's time to fix that.  This will be messy and no fun and is just a matter of fixing it and maybe using `git rebase -i` to put the fixup in the right place, or whatever.  That's a matter for a separate question (but there are already a bunch that will get you there).

If everything is perfect, or after you've fixed things up, at this point you're ready to make this third repository your *main* repository: just *remove* the `two` remote, and rename the `one` remote to `origin`:

```
git remote remove two
git remote rename one origin
```

The first command drops the `two/master` remote-tracking name entirely.  The second one changes `one/master` to `origin/master`, and you can now rename `rebuild` to whatever feature name you'd like:

```
git branch -m rebuild feature-X
```

and run `git push origin feature-X` to send the new (copied) commits to GitHub and be ready to make a pull request.

#### Coda: why we can't cherry-pick `N`

When we start with something like:

```
A--B--...--G--H   <-- one/master

N--O--...--V--W   <-- two/master
```

you might be tempted to create `master` (or `rebuild`) pointing to commit `H`, then run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-N>
```

This doesn't work!  The reason why becomes clear when you think about how `git cherry-pick` does its job.  It works by *comparing* the commit you tell it to cherry-pick to that commit's parent.

Commit `N` *has no parent*.  Cherry-pick could just give up—it could say *I don't have a parent for that commit* and stop—but instead, it plays a game of pretend: it pretends that commit `N` has a parent that has *no files in it at all*.

What this means is that for the purpose of copying commit `N`, the action that cherry-pick needs to replay is to *create every file that is in it*.  Most of those files, maybe even all of them, probably already exist in commit `H`, which also gets compared to an empty commit, so that the merge operation is attempting to combine "add all of `H`'s files" with "add all of `N`'s files".  The result is a mass of "add/add conflicts", so that Git might as well have just given up originally.

Comment: your legend!!! thank you for your explanation, it does help me get to know more about git, the point is that i did exactly the same as your instruction, and judging from the "gitk", the results seems to successfully joined the commit history, but still i can't send a pull request, it still shows that branch has completely different history, Do you have any idea what might happened here? I did encounter several conflict during cherry picking, i checked with "git status", and manually added the files that shows both modified, does that affect the result?

Comment: It sounds like you built a new branch tip correctly, but then ran `git push` on the *old* name—the equivalent of `git push origin two/master:pr`—or else forgot to first delete the old PR and were unable to overwrite the old PR. However, aside from the need to set up the first copy carefully, there *should* have been no conflicts at all, as long as the commits you were cherry-picking were all neatly in graph order (*not* date order as dates can go backwards; graph order is required).

Comment: I like how you properly explained the 2 situations, the one with exact match, and the one without. Have my upvote

Comment: sorry for the late reply!! it worked, the first time i cherry picked with one line and it ended up with wrong merge result, i tried it again and it worked, not sure what happened but at least get me back on track, really appreciated and have my upvote~